# why do we use the equation we do for special relativity when there is a shorter, more intuitive one?

Tags: special-relativity

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ is the equation physicists use to calculate time dilation.Why don't they use $\sqrt{1+v^2/c^2}$ which is faster and also more intuitive (for me at least)

Although now I see why they are not equivalent (when I compared the two equations I was using v=4000-50000) I don't understand why my equation is wrong. if you have a right angle triangle and the hypotenuse is t' and the height is t, surely if you divide t' by t it will give the ratio between the two. What is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Because it's not true.

Comment: Was it a mistake that you put a + sign rather than a - sign in the second equation? If you meant to write sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2) then that quantity is usually labeled beta, and 1/beta can indeed be used in place of the the relativistic gamma factor in relativistic equations. But if you put + on purpose I don't understand the question--putting that equation in place of the gamma factor would give completely different predictions, which as Javier Badia says would just be incorrect.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, it is 1/sqrt(1-v^2/c^2) that is usually labeled beta, not its reciprocal.

Comment: @Joshua - no, that quantity is labeled gamma. But I was wrong too, I looked it up and it's just v/c that's labeled beta, so sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2) would be the same as sqrt(1 - beta^2).

Comment: @Hypnosifl, aha, indeed.  We were both confused.

Answer (score 8):

The [MacLaurin series expansion of the Lorentz factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor#Series_expansion_.28velocity.29) is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} + \frac{3}{8}\left(\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^2 +\; ... $$

So, for $v\ll c$, the first two terms give a good approximation to the actual value.

It turns out that the MacLaurin expansion of another function has the same first two terms:

$$\sqrt{1 + \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} - \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^2 \; ...$$

So, you see, as long $v$ is *small enough* such that the 3rd and higher order terms are insignificant, the two functions give approximately the same answer.

In fact, if $v$ is small enough to use $\sqrt{1 + \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$, why not use $1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}$ instead?

Comment: Thank you, very good answer. Although now I see why they are not equivalent (when I compared the two equations I was using v=4000-50000) I don't understand why my equation is wrong. if you have a right angle triangle and the hypotenuse is t' and the height is t, surely if you divide t' by t it will give the ratio between the two. What is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: @Ray Kay - are you imagining that the other side of the right triangle is of length v/c? Keep in mind that spacetime is a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) so the formula for calculating the "length" of the hypotenuse C of a small right triangle with sides A and B does not obey the formula A^2 + B^2 = C^2 as it would in a Riemannian manifold. Are you familiar with the notion of the [Space-time interval](http://www.physics.fsu.edu/users/ProsperH/AST3033/relativity/Interval.htm), which is analogous to the concept of "path length" in space?

Comment: No I'm not, I'll do some research on it. Since my equation is accurate until the velocity is ridiculously fast -it would require a ridiculously fast speed to show it is wrong. Has experiment been done to show this?

Comment: @RayKay, the equation you give is falsified by many experiments involving ultra-relativistic speeds.  For example:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation_of_moving_particles#Frisch-Smith_experiment  In this case, the particles were ultra-relativistic ($v$ approaching $c$) and the measured time dilation was roughly 8.  But 'your' equation predicts the time dilation should be $\sqrt{2}$ when $v = c$ so experiment rules it out.

Answer (score 6):

$1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ is only *approximately* equal to $\sqrt{1+v^2/c^2}$ for small $v$. As $v \to \pm c$, the error grows arbitrarily large. The former is always right, the latter is not.

This is just the same as how $1/(1-x) \approx 1 + x$, where the approximation is only good for small values of $x$. If the cost of a product goes down by $5\%$ ($x = 0.05$), the same money can purchase *approximately* $1.05$ times as much of it. But clearly if the cost goes down by $99\%$ ($x = 0.99$) you can purchase $100$ times as much ($1/(1-0.99) = 100$), not just twice as much ($1+0.99 = 1.99$).